# Why is the log date time information being truncated in Pentaho Data Integration 9.2 against the Snowflake database?

Tags: logging, etl, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am migrating our Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) logging to Snowflake DB instead of SQL Server. I was able to generate the tables against Snowflake using Kettle. When I run a kettle job, the logs are stored in the snowflake database. However, the HHMMSS are truncated. If I run a transformation, the logdate is stored as today at midnight rather than capturing the hour minutes and seconds it was ran. Is there a setting that I am missing in Pentaho?

```
CREATE TABLE "MySchema"."TransformationLogTable"
(
  "ID_BATCH" INT
, "CHANNEL_ID" VARCHAR(255)
, "TRANSNAME" VARCHAR(255)
, "STATUS" VARCHAR(15)
, "LINES_READ" BIGINT
, "LINES_WRITTEN" BIGINT
, "LINES_UPDATED" BIGINT
, "LINES_INPUT" BIGINT
, "LINES_OUTPUT" BIGINT
, "LINES_REJECTED" BIGINT
, "ERRORS" BIGINT
, "STARTDATE" TIMESTAMP_LTZ
, "ENDDATE" TIMESTAMP_LTZ
, "LOGDATE" TIMESTAMP_LTZ
, "DEPDATE" TIMESTAMP_LTZ
, "REPLAYDATE" TIMESTAMP_LTZ
, "LOG_FIELD" VARCHAR(9999999)
);
```

[image: Pentaho Log Info]